Can Wix Bundle not Uninstall something if it didn't install it
(Hi Rob, love your work! (And Bob, And contributors))
I have a small problem. I made an installer to install some certificates (turned it into an MSI)and I also have some other .msis that need to be included in the bundle. I made the bundle check if the version of the windows is 32bit or 64bit and then install the necessary MSIs.
However, when installing the bundle it correctly checks if one or more of the MSIs is present on the PC and skips installing it (yaaay). Although, when uninstalling, even if it didn't install something from its bundle, but the MSI was already installed (before or in a different way), it will also uninstall that MSI from the PC. How do I tell the bundle not to uninstall that MSI if it didn't install it?
Installed the bundle, it skipped installing the already installed MSI's but it uninstalled them when I uninstalled the bundle.
